# Trouble duplicating a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript and jQuery and I'm trying to clone the "Person[1]" div inside the "peopleID" div with the click of the button as many times as needed and I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sohjiro/14b98x2g/)

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    var clonedDiv = $('#Person[1]').clone();
    $('#peopleID').after(clonedDiv);
  });
});
```

HTML Code

```
<form>
  <input id="add" value="Add Additional Field" type="button">
  <div id="peopleID">
    <div id="Person[1]">
      <select name="Personnel[1]">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't use special characters in IDs like '[]'. Your id should be "Person1". Check updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/14b98x2g/13/  Also, you can escape special characters  "Person\\\[1\\\]"

Comment: omg thank you so much I've been dying trying to find out what i was doing wrong thank you

Comment: Note that you will get multiple elements with the same id. Better change the id after cloning to the next running number.

Comment: I will be I just was simplifying it to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [escape square bracket in selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) since it has special meaning in [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) otherwise, it will search for an element with id `Person` and has attribute `1` since square bracket act as [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

```
$('#Person\\[1\\]').clone();
```

---

Or you can use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as an alternative.

```
$('[id="Person[1]"]').clone();
```